# How can I use OR logic in @Isgranted for Symfony 4.4

Tags: symfony, permissions, annotations, symfony4-voter

I'm in Symfony 4.4

My first permission is

```
 * @IsGranted(
 *     ModulePermission::MODULE_MODERATOR,
 *     subject="module",
 * )
```

My second permission is

```
 * @IsGranted(
 *     ItemPermission::DELETE_ITEM,
 *     subject="cm",
 * )
```

Every permission works independently as expected, but as I don't have access yet to @security (update to SF5 scheduled but not done), how can I use both permission in my controller for MODULE_MODERATOR **OR** DELETE_ITEM ?

I have tried different 'googled' solution without success:

Access denied:

```
 * @IsGranted(
 *     "is_granted('ITEM_PERMISSION::DELETE_ITEM',cm) OR is_granted('MODULE_PERMISSION::MODULE_MODERATOR',module)",
 * )
```

Access denied:

```
 * @IsGranted(
 *     "ITEM_PERMISSION::DELETE_ITEM cm OR ModulePermission::MODULE_MODERATOR module",
 * )
```

Comment: There are expressions you can try but if you really need this sort of logic then custom voters are probably the way to go.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/security/expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you can only concatenate your isGranted annotations (it's even an example in documentation: https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/security.html#isgranted):

```
/*
 * @IsGranted(ModulePermission::MODULE_MODERATOR, subject="module")
 * @IsGranted(ItemPermission::DELETE_ITEM, subject="cm")
 */
```

They say in this documentation:

> Each IsGranted() must grant access for the user to have access to the controller.

But it's weird according to their example (being ADMIN + having right SHOW the post), moreover, Symfony applies the stategy "affirmative" by default for the voters, it means:

> This grants access as soon as there is one voter granting access;

Comment: Thanks Vincent, but I have tested with the concatenation, if both conditions are not granted the access is rejected. The best to do is to adapt my voters until the upgrade of the Sf version.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I didn't have time to check and doc was a little unclear to me, sorry for your time loss